# ClipPlane orientation

Tags: graphics3d, options, gui-construction

I'm trying to clip a cone both from top and bottom using `IntervalSlider`. I'm able to clip it from the bottom but not from the top.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Green, Pink], Cone[]}, 
  ClipPlanes -> {InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, z[[1]]}, {1, 0, z[[1]]}, {0, 1,
        z[[1]]}}], 
    InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, -z[[2]]}, {1, 0, -z[[2]]}, {0, 
       1, -z[[2]]}}]}], {z, -1, 1, ControlType -> IntervalSlider, 
 Method -> "Push", MinIntervalSize -> 0.1}]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, how to specify that the plane should cut content below or above itself.

#### Answer

I couldn't find notes about that in documentation but it seems, and is reasonable, that the order of points in `InfinitePlane's` specification determines that. So if you reverse the order of points in the second plane you will get what you need.

#### Tip

Clipping is controlled by FE so you can use `ClipPlanes -> Dynamic[...]`. This will improve performance as the whole `Graphics3D` will not need to be recreated each time.

#### Final code

```
Manipulate[
     Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Green, Pink], Cone[]}
       , ClipPlanes -> Dynamic@{
           InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, z[[1]]}, {1, 0, z[[1]]}, {0, 1, z[[1]]}}], 
           InfinitePlane[
             Reverse@{{0, 0, z[[2]]}, {1, 0, z[[2]]}, {0, 1, z[[2]]}}
           ]
         }
     ]
  , {z, -1, 1
    , ControlType -> IntervalSlider
    , Method -> "Push"
    , MinIntervalSize -> 0.1
    }
]
```

[image]