# Blinking cells after Manipulate

Tags: front-end, manipulate, gui-construction

I call this `Manipulate` from a package:

```
GraficoSeno[]:= {Manipulate[pntx=First[pt]; pnty=Last[pt];
        Graphics[{{Red, Circle[]},
        {Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, pt}]},
        {Point[{{0,0},{0,pnty}}]},
        {Point[{{0,0},{pntx,0}}]},
        {Thick, Line[{{0,0},{0,pnty}},VertexColors->{Blue, Blue}]}, 
        {Thick, Line[{{pntx,0}, pt},VertexColors->{Blue, Blue}]}},
        Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 3/2],
        {{pt, {1, 1}/Sqrt[2]}, Locator, TrackingFunction ->((pt = Normalize[#]) &)},ContentSize->{300,300}]
};
```

Suddenly this strange thing happens:

```
https://streamable.com/l8szp
```

Why is that blinking happening?

Comment: That happened because of i used, as Kuba suggest, pntx as a shared variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pnty, pntx` are not scoped. If many instances of your gui share them, change in any will trigger each other resulting in a loop.

You can scope it as follows:

```
DynamicModule[{pnty, pntx}, Manipulate[...
```

But this makes the performance of Locators really bad. I don't know why but it should not happen.

`Manipulate` is a big black box, I don't think there is a point in spending time investigating that issue. For more complicate case you can rewrite everything as `DynamicModule` and for less, like here, we can scope `pnty` in `Manipulate` itself with `{pnty, None}` variable spec, see more in:

[What does None mean in a control specification for Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17112/5478)

```
GraficoSeno[] := {Manipulate[    
    Graphics[
     { {Red, Circle[]}
     , {Thick, Dynamic @ Line[{{0, 0}, pt}]}
     , {Dynamic @ Point[{{0, 0}, {0, pnty}}]}
     , {Dynamic @ Point[{{0, 0}, {pntx, 0}}]}
     , {Thick, Blue, Dynamic @ Line[{{0, 0}, {0, pnty}}]}
     , {Thick, Blue, Dynamic@Line[{{pntx, 0}, pt}]}
     }
     , Axes -> True
     , PlotRange -> 3/2
    ]
  , {{pt, {1, 1}/Sqrt[2]}, Locator, TrackingFunction -> ((pt = Normalize[#]; {pntx, pnty} = pt) &)}
  , {pntx, None}
  , {pnty, None}
  , ContentSize -> {300, 300}
]}
```

p.s. I've moved `pntx` to the `TrackingFunction`, as well as I've added `Dynamic` inside `Graphics`, this way the whole `Graphics` does not have to be recreated when you move controllers. See e.g.:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143939/5478